# NetLogo Behavior Space : how to assign a customized name for csv file columns?

Tags: netlogo

I was wondering if there is any way to have a predefined name for behaviorspace result column name, for example if one of the outputs is `count agents with [some condition]` , instead of  `Count agents with [some condition]` column name be   `The condition` .

Currently I have defined a global variable with my desired column name and I update it at the end of experiment run, but if my experiment ends with an error, I will get zero instead of that variable. Is there any other way for having proper column name?

Thanks :)

Comment: Andrew, may I suggest that your "put on hold" trigger finger is a little itchy? This is a perfectly good, clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a procedure:

```
to-report the-condition
  report count agents with [...]
end
```

then in the BehaviorSpace experiment, change the metric to `the-condition`.

Comment: Is there any simple way to use same to-report for different time steps? For example initial and final reporter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Isn't that exactly what happens when you add `the-condition` to the "Measure runs using these reporters" section of your experiment definition?

Comment: When I run the experiments I unchecked the box to measure runs at every step and then it only gives me the final results, now I am using global varibles for initial values of agents attributes for example InitailWeath "sum [x] of agents with [C1] " and I need final wealth at 40000 ticks  "sum [x] of agents with [C1] " the reporter only gives me the final value.

Comment: If you want to collect only initial and final results, check the "Measure runs at every step" checkbox, but then run an experiment that only lasts for one step and have the go commands be `repeat 40000 [ go ]`.